# How do you access the DLC for Darksouls 3?

Tags: ps4, dark-souls-3

I just purchased the DLC for DarkSouls3 and It is my first time purchasing DLC content. I have spent some time trying to find information for this title but to no avail. I am not sure how to access the DLC for this game on the PS4 and would appreciate the advise of someone out there who is familiar with this. thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- there isn't any DLC available for Dark Souls 3 yet. Are you talking about a pre-order bonus or something?

Comment: @pushasha I assume OP preordered DLC. It's not out yet, but preorders have been available as long as the game, I think.

Comment: The DLC is included in the "seasons pass" I purchased today. It says in the information on the product that is there when you purchase that you gain access to 2 epic DLC packs.

Comment: I had thought that in typical darksouls style that the DLC levels would be subtle and possibly hard to find.

Comment: @Rhaunn See my answer below. The season pass grants you access to the DLC, but only once it has been released. But your assumption that the DLC might be hard to find is a reasonable one :)

Comment: @Rhaunn Always happy to be your source for DS info. I don't blame you for being confused -- the PSN store description for the Season Pass makes it sound as if the DLC is available immediately after purchase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downloadable content for Dark Souls 3 has not been released in any territory at this time (08/31/16).

The first DLC, [*Ashes of Ariandel* will be released on October 25th, 2016](http://fextralife.com/dark-souls-3-dlc-revealed-ashes-of-ariandel-on-october-25th-trailer-screenshots-and-more/). To get this DLC, you can either order the Season Pass (which it sounds like you already did), which will grant access to all future DLC, or you can buy the DLC by itself. The season pass can be purchased on the Playstation store right now, but the listings for individual DLCs will be only be available on the store when they are released.

To clarify, if you buy/bought the season pass, you will not have access to the DLC immediately after purchase -- you must wait for the release date. When the release date arrives, go to the Playstation Store page for the DLC, and select the "Download" option.

Comment: The DLC is by now released for owners for the Season Pass on Xbox One. However, I can't access it. I have looked at videos, but it's not working. I have the Season Pass and the game is up to date.

Comment: @Exa This question was specifically asking about the PS4 version. I'm not sure how the Xbox One version is handled.